# Is it possible to use PyBluez on Windows to turn my computer into an HID device?

Tags: python, bluetooth, emulation, hid, pybluez

In fact, I want to control the iPhone camera to take photos via Bluetooth. I already know that if I can send Volume Up to the iPhone (some phone Bluetooth shutters are based on this principle), then I can achieve this function. I have searched a lot of information, and it seems that it can only be implemented under Linux. However, I want to implement this feature on Windows.

I tried to use GPT-4 to provide a solution, but the code it provided couldn't run, and it seems to be only runnable on Linux as well. I also saw some dbus solutions, but it seems that dbus also only has Linux solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.